# Show edittext when soft keyboard appear in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have some edittext on my layout, when I click on the edittext for filling it the softkeyboard appear and everything in fine, I can see the input and the softkeyboard but when I click on the edittexts at the bottom of the layout the softkeyboard appear and the edittext is not visible while I'm typing, I have to scroll down to see it. Is there any way to automatically scroll to the edittext so I can see when I'm typing and the softkeyboard at the same time?

Comment: Post you layout code.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this to your activity tag in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [developers blog _ On-screen Input Methods](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html).

Summing up I guess this line should help you:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```